# If check box is cheked show/hide div (by searching trough object property)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making one web site, and I'm stuck. I have 6 checkboxes:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Pizza" id="pizza">
         Pizza 
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="BBQ" id="bbq">
         BBQ
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Chicken" id="chicken">
         Chicken
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Pasta" id="pasta">
         Pasta
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Chinese" id="chinese">
         Chinese
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Mexican" id="mexican">
         Mexican
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="Indian" id="indian">
         Indian
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class = "restaurant" id="Paradiso">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class = "restaurant" id="Wingsy">
    </div>
    </div>
```

And a lot more of restaurant class div's.

So, I want to make: when checkbox are cheked they search trough restaurants and if that restourant have property that is in checkbox, it shows. Otherwise it hides.

Example:

```
 var typeOfKitchen = ['pizza','bbq','chicken','pasta','chinese','mexican','indian'];

 var restaurants = new Array();

 restaurant = new Object();
 restaurant.[name] = "Paradiso";
 restaurant.[type] = typeOfKitchen[0];
 restaurants.push(restaurant);

 restaurant = new Object();
 restaurant.[name] = "Wingsy";
 restaurant.[type] = typeOfKitchen[2];
 restaurants.push(restaurant);
```

And then I'm stuck with code to take value of checkbox and search trough restaurants and shows only restaurants who have that property, and hide others that dont have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is good practise to use jsFiddle to show your code.

Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EtJ6L/5/

I had restructured your code a bit, added some css and js.

New HTML code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pizza" id="pizza" />
    <label>Pizza</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="BBQ" id="bbq" />
    <label>BBQ</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Chicken" id="chicken" />
    <label>Chicken</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pasta" id="pasta" />
    <label>Pasta</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Chinese" id="chinese" />
    <label>Chinese</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mexican" id="mexican" />
    <label>Mexican</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Indian" id="indian" />
    <label>Indian</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="restaurant" id="pizza">Paradiso</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="restaurant" id="bbq">Wingsy</div>
</div>
```

Added CSS:

```
.restaurant {
    display: none;
}
```

Added jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".restaurant#" + id).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

**How it works?**

Notice, that I changed block with info about restraunts. Now name of restraunt (and other info will be there too) is inner html of div. Also, to achieve what you want you have to connect restraunt blocks with inputs.

Look this block html, for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="restaurant" id="bbq">Wingsy</div>
</div>
```

Firstly, name is inner hmtl. Also, I added type of restraunt into `id` attribute of this div.

Look this input html (connected with restraunt):

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="BBQ" id="bbq" />
    <label>BBQ</label>
</div>
```

Firstly, I restrucutred it a bit. Now it is more valid, than was. Also, notice `id` attribute of this input. So input and divs are connected now.

Divs with restraunt's info are hidden from start. It is achieved by css code `display: none`.

Now take a look on jQuery code.

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".restaurant#" + id).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

We handling change action on all checkbox elements on page. We save id of checkbox was clicked on. After that we toggle `.restraunt#xxx` element, where xxx is id of this element. Div's and input's are connected, so this approach will work. Toggle displays or hide element. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) about it.

Hope this will help you.

**Note** I think better approach is to make ajax request to the server depending on checkbox checked, then cache and output ajax response.

**If you have situation, that restraunt can have more then 1 kitchen** As I said earlier better way is to use ajax request. You will send some parameters like `bbq=true&pizza=true`, server will handle this query and will return some response, depending on query. I had written an example for you. Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EtJ6L/8/.

On checkbox click ajax request sending to script `bob.php`, for example. Look, what data is sending with it. On `bob.php` you will handle this query. Something like `$pizza = $_POST['pizza']; if($pizza != "") { // add something to sql query }` etc.

Comment: Tnx for the problem solution. It is good. It is my fault that I didn't mentioned folowing: For example , there will be restaurants that have pizza and bbq and chicken type of kitchen. And that can't be done with with this code. Sorry.

Comment: I had given answer for asked question. Edit your question then.

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to use ajax requests in that situation. It will be dirty solution, as I think, using pure jQuery there.

Comment: I had edited my answer again. I added example with ajax request. Hope this will help you.